# How to decode opaque Access Token with Oauth2.0

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, decode, openid-connect

I have got a token key which contains the logged in person email address as well as the name and other end points.This was actually used in xero API connection.

```
scope = 'offline_access accounting.reports.read accounting.settings.read openid profile email'
```

I need to decode this token key and get the logged in email address and the name of the person who is logged in.

For an example my token key is as below.

```
b9b73c12b40a3bc1441f5bda331c4d7c64c0394956d5105eec61a71de19f8153
```

How can I decode this opaque Access Token and get the relevant information using python.

Comment: does your token look like what you have shown in the example (no JWT and probably an opaque token) or is it a JWT which looks like eyJxxxxx.eyxxxxx.yyyyyy (three parts separated by `.` and part 1 and two beginning with 'ey')?

Comment: @jps Hi,,Yes the token key looks like in the way I have provided.Can we decode that and get the user email address,And how I can do it,,Thanks for your cooperation

Comment: And also I used OAuth2.0

Comment: I edited the problem to reflect this opaque access token

Comment: it's in the nature of [opaque tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158410/what-is-an-opaque-token/59158631#59158631) that they're not meant to be decoded/decrypted by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clients should never decode access tokens directly, as jps says. You have these options:

**READ USER FIELDS FROM ID TOKEN**

The UI reads this JWT directly. An id token always has JWT format and is designed to be read by clients.

**USE USER INFO ENDPOINT**

The UI can send the access token to the User Info endpoint, using the message from step 24 of the above blog post.

**GET USER INFO FROM API**

This tends to be the most extensible option, since you can return any info you want, and you are not limited to what is contained in access tokens.

Comment: Your link is broken

Answer (score 0):

```
const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]; //Bearer +token
const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, "secret_message_long_string");
req.userData = { email: decodedToken.email, userId: decodedToken.userId };
```

This example is for decoding data for nodejs.

try the same way in python. Importing jwt and using the method verfiy passing the token and secret string as an argument.

Comment: sorry, but this answer doesn't make much sense. The question was about python, but you answer for node.js. Then the question did not show a JWT but an opaque token, so that this code wouldn't work. And even in case of a JWT, there are already many answers that show how to decode a JWT, so it would be a duplicate answer anyway.