# Azure AD Opaque token Validation

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, single-page-application, azure-ad-msal

In Azure Ad, If you have (SPA & API) app and in backend you receive the access token (opaque not jwt) what do you do validate the (AUD or appId or clientId) of the token. You can verify the token by calling Graph API, or you don't need to verify it?

#Edit:
I verify the token by calling (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me) and send the opaque token as an access token.

Comment: Could you also include how are you validating token?

Comment: I can't validate the token claims like (aud, appId) as it's opaque not a jwt, but I can verify that it's a valid token by calling graph API (/me) with the token in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: Azure Active Directory/Microsoft Entra ID do not support opaque tokens and introspection.

- According to this [**blog**](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens#opaque-access-tokens), there is no need to validate the opaque access tokens.
- You can just call the just call any user info endpoint.

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

- Token introspection is not stored in a JWT format. The resource API can't interpret the opaque string that token introspection uses.
- Microsoft uses CAE, that is if as long as the token is valid, resource owner accepts it upon validation. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/zero-trust/develop/secure-with-cae).

For **example**, if the application is calling Microsoft Graph API, then the events received from Microsoft Entra ID can be checked by Microsoft Graph.

- If the original authentication condition is changed then the user should reauthenticate. An error will be thrown by Microsoft Graph.

**Reference:**

[oauth 2.0 - validate opaque access token by Azure AD - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336907/validate-opaque-access-token-by-azure-ad) by Amir Keibi

Comment: So, from backend perspective, I don't have to make sure that this token was issued for my application, and I don't need to check the (Audience) or the (appId/clientId)?

Comment: AFAIK no need of validating them